# Connecting the spade terminals to a new fridge thermostat

Tags: thermostat, refrigerator

can anyone tell me which connections I fit the spade terminals to in a new fridge thermostat? I stupidly forgot to photograph the old one.
Many thanks

Comment: Make/model number?

Comment: Will need to google that for the make and model and maybe year of fridge.  Imagine almost every fridge is a bit different.

Comment: It is a Bosch Classic. Model number;  KSR32623GB/04. I have the new thermostat in but not sure which of the two remaining terminals I fit the grey wire to

Comment: A photo of the board may be enough.

Comment: @IanCrowe it's always worth clicking the [edit] button and putting that info into the question itself. Sometimes comments get deleted and critical info can get lost.